# Web Content file not getting created under project, instead WEB-INF getting created under webapp under src>main

Tags: eclipse, servlets

I created a new dynamic web project in latest version of eclipse.

Instead of creating ProjectName > Web Content > web inf, its creating src > webapp > web-inf.

Has something changed ineclipse?

I am learning servlets and evefy tutorial has web-inf under WebContent folder in all the tutorials.

Is there any updated tutorial to learn servlets from which matches current eclipse's project structure.

Much Thanks & Regards

project structure chnaged, no tutorials with updated project structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Has something changed ineclipse?

Yes, the defaults as you went through the new project wizard. Other than the paths, there's no difference.